# How should we call our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

I recently renamed our chat name and description, and now they are:

> #### lɪŋgwɪstɪks
>
> wɛlkəm tu lɪŋgwɪstɪks!

But a proposal was thrown to ask the community about it and decide together. Do you have a proposal?

Structure your answer like:

```
> ### Title

>  Description
```

Obviously, **vote up** proposals you like and **vote down** proposals you don't like! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think using the IPA transcription would make our chat unique in the whole SE network. :D

Therefore, my proposal is to keep the title and change the description adding a link to the Main site, but still using IPA:

> #### lɪŋgwɪstɪks
>
> tʃæt ruːm fɔr ðə [lɪŋgwɪstɪks stæk ɪkstʃeɪndʒ saɪt](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)
>
> <sub>*The quote above says* "Linguistics: Chat room for the Linguistics Stack Exchange site".</sub>

There might be mistakes in the IPA transcription but this is just the idea, we can correct it. :)

**Edit**: I want to add that actually the title is what I'm **really** proposing, since I think that "lɪŋgwɪstɪks" is as powerful as it is simple. I'm open to suggestions concerning the description, but I really think that using IPA would make our chat peculiar.

Comment: I guess it's part way between American and British IPA. British would have the long vowel diacritic `ː` after the `u` in `rum` -> `ruːm`. American might use a different `r` or a rhotic version of the `ɔ`. I'm not really sure because American IPA is rare in comparison to British. In either case the vowel in "exchange" should be `eɪ` and "site" should be `saɪt`.

Comment: @hippietrail I used a site to transcribe it, so there certainly are some mistakes. :D

Comment: Yes, contrary to popular opinion there are many ways to use the IPA (-:

Comment: By the way, I agree on the `saɪt` part, but i didn't bother correcting it earlier. I'll fix it now. Also, both AmE and BrE accept both "ruːm" or "rʊm" for [room](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/room). Maybe "for" is a weak form here? Uhm... *thinking*

Comment: NaNS (Not a Native Speaker), but I'd have used [fəɹ], ɹ instead of r. Or ɾ if you want the tʃæt ruːm to have a Scottish accent ;)

Comment: `/-ɛndʒ/` is a very rare syllable in English. [So rare it's not even in Wiktionary's rhymes page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rhymes:English:Stressed_on_/%C9%9B/) and the only word I can think of that uses it is ["henge"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/henge). (Note that whether to use "e" or "ɛ" is pretty much a matter of taste in English IPA.)

Comment: Like I said, the transcription was done automatically through a site and I didn't correct it right away. I'll fix that too.

Answer (score 2):

> #### Tower of Babel
>
> Named for the famous scene in the old testament.

Comment: Would you mind to explain why it'd fit our Linguistics site? I fail to understand that... :P

Comment: It's the scene in the bible that explains [why there are many languages spoken in the world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythical_origins_of_language) rather than [just one "Adamic" language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamic_language). The Holy Spirit ["confused the tongues"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_of_tongues) so the people building [the tower to heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel) couldn't communicate and hence cooperate and the tower would fail.

Comment: Ah that! I think I heard it once but didn't link to it. :)

Comment: I was thinking... This is not a bad name, but I see it fit much better on the Languages site rather than the Linguistics site. :D

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Alenanno about IPA. It gives personality to our room and we should definitely use it! Now, to the name: what about "Lingua Franca"? In the English rendition of the phrase:

> **ˈlɪŋɡwə fɹæŋkə**

Or, perhaphs more appropriately, in the Latin rendition of it:

> **ˈliŋɡwa fɾaŋka**

I think this name would be nice, first of all, because it is a common expression that is obviously related to languages and language studies. Most people will recognize the phrase. But also, to reflect the fact that SE chat rooms in general, and ours in particular, are spaces where users – most of them non-native English speakers – use English every day as a lingua franca.

Comment: Excellent! I like this. And we should use the Latin pronunciation:  not only does the English pronunciation deviate more from the original than any other pronunciation, but it would also be rather arbitrary, since English is only one possible language, and not the one in which the phrase was coined.

Comment: What about the description? Have you thought about it? :)

Comment: No, I haven't. If someone has any suggestion, I would be very interested to hear.

Answer (score 0):

> #### Speaking in tongues
>
> An English idiom that seems applicable.